# Replacing all matching nodes in XML using XSLT

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, xslcompiledtransform, xpathdocument

I wanted to replace all matching nodes in the xml-file.

To the original xml:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <StackPanel>
    <Button/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I applied the following xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Button">
        <AnotherButton><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></AnotherButton>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it produces the same xml. What I did wrong?

Comment: **Default Namespace!!!**

Comment: Your Button is in a namespace, but your match pattern says "match a 'Button' not in a namespace" - hence no match.

Comment: Yes, it works now. Thanks. Is there any way to add those namaspaces to xslt to make it work without removing namespaces from the original xml?

Answer (score 3):

What Sean is saying is that if you remove the namespace from your XML document the XSLT will work

```
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <Button/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

produces...

```
<Window>
    <StackPanel>
        <AnotherButton />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Alternatively**, you asked if you can keep your namespace

Add your `x:` namespace to your Button...

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <StackPanel>
    <x:Button/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Update your XSL to also use this `x:Button` namespace

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:Button">
        <x:AnotherButton><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></x:AnotherButton>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces...

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <x:AnotherButton/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```